# Logstash: How to use date/time in a filename as an imported field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have a bunch of log files that are named as 'XXXXXX_XX_yymmdd_hh:mm:ss.txt' - I need to include the date and time (separate fields) from the filename in fields that are added to Logstash.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) to extract the date and time:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "path",
      "^%{GREEDYDATA}/[^/]+_%{INT:date}_%{TIME:time}\.txt$"
    ]
  }
}
```

Depending on what goes instead of XXXXXX_XX you might prefer a stricter expression. Also, GREEDYDATA isn't very efficient. This might yield better performance:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "path", "^(?:/[^/]+)+/[^/]+_%{INT:date}_%{TIME:time}\.txt$"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can replace the @timestamp value with the time contained within each line of the log file? Each line starts "08:55:43.23" (no quotes). I'd like to take the date from the file name + time in the log file

Comment: Create a field (possibly with the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date)) that concatenates the date field picked up from the filename with the time from the log message and use the [date filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/date) to populate the `@timestamp` field.

Comment: Can what you posted above be used in conjunction with what I currently have? i.e. can I put the match statement below this? grok {
match => [ "message", "%{TIME:timestamp},%{WORD:agent},%{NUMBER:agentid},%{NUMBER:campaignid},%{CISCO_REASON:campaign_name},%{NUMBER:unknown1},%{NUMBER:unknown2},%{NUMBER:unknown3},%{NUMBER:unknown4},%{NUMBER:unknown5},%{NUMBER:unknown6},%{NUMBER:unknown7},%{NUMBER:unknown8},%{CISCO_REASON:Status}" ]
}

Comment: Sure. Your two grok filters parse different fields so they're not in conflict and they don't have an order dependency.

Comment: Should your suggestion work in Grok Debugger? I'm seeing 'No Matches' when using the following input "C:/inetpub/tslogs/ACTrace_ACTAT_150202_100034.txt" (no quotes)

Comment: The first example works with Windows paths. The second one doesn't (but could be made to work with a minor change).

Comment: Sorry to sound like I need to be spoon fed, but are you able to help me with the syntax? I've tried #logstash to no avail. I need the date from the filename and time from each event in the log...

Comment: Just prepend the second expression with "C:" and it'll match Windows paths too.