# bad Timestamp in Filebeat for syslog file

Tags: linux, timestamp, syslog, filebeat

I've configured ELK server with filebeat on client. The configuration seems ok but when i search for my log with kibana every syslog entry are refferenced in year 2000 like this :

```
{
  "_index": "filebeat-2000.02.09",
  "_type": "syslog",
  "_id": "AVLGZIPtL5gIGucGObzD",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "Feb  9 15:54:01 dev postfix/qmgr[1164]: 7DF9D1803D0: removed",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2000-02-09T14:54:01.000Z",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "dev",
      "name": "dev"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "fields": null,
    "input_type": "log",
    "offset": 156454,
    "source": "/var/log/syslog",
    "type": "syslog",
.....
```

when i looked into my /var/log/syslog file I have this kind of line :

```
Feb  9 16:36:01 dev postfix/qmgr[1164]: 51F48180484: from=<root@dev>, size=1838, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb  9 16:36:01 dev postfix/local[2884]: 51F48180484: to=<root@dev>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.05/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

There's no year in the line start.

My question is, how to add the year or change the timestamp ?
I use Debian 8.2
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384754/syslog-timestamp-without-year

Comment: I've seen this post but if i reset th log of a client started since more than one year it will not work, i'm looking for change the syslog file to keep same data on elk and server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the `syslog` setting `$ActionFileDefaultTemplate` from default `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` to `RSYSLOG_FileFormat` which has timestamp in `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601` format.

Edit the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file.

```
#$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_FileFormat
```

Then restart `rsyslogd` daemon.

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

So the log format will be similar to this:

```
2016-02-07T03:47:14.300009+01:00 foo rhsmd: This system is registered to RHN Classic.
```

Comment: One line command: `sed -i -e 's/RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat/RSYSLOG_FileFormat/g' /etc/rsyslog.conf && systemctl restart rsyslog`